# Sort specific parts in String

Tags: java, string, sorting

Alright so, I have a String which contains:
`1 456 2 100 3 600 1 400`

The 1 is the Id of a person which got a score of 456 and 400.
2 is the Id of a person which got a score of 100 etc.

I need the String to sort by **values** and not by **id's**. It should look like this: `2 100 1 400 1 456 3 600`

I already tried putting it into a hashmap and sorting it, but since a hashmap doesn't take identical keys, this is not an option.

Comment: You should create a class and put the id and value in the class.  Add each instance of the class to a list and sort the list as required.

Comment: other options to consider: Records instead of classes to cut out on boiler plate code, or you could use Tuples (Pair)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full [snippet](http://tpcg.io/_K8FBFS), but as WJS [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75271649/sort-specific-parts-in-string#comment132823777_75271649), create a class:

```
public class Person {
    private String id;
    private int score;
    ...
}
```

Then add these to a List:

```
...
String[] parts = s.split(" ");
    
List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i += 2) {
    String id = parts[i];
    int score = Integer.parseInt(parts[i+1]);
    people.add(new Person(id, score));
}
```

Then you sort the list by passing a comparator which compares `scores` and if you need it back in a String, join the list with spaces:

```
people.sort((p1, p2) -> Integer.compare(p1.score, p2.score));    
String result = people.stream().map(Person::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Comment: ```people.sort((p1, p2) -> Integer.compare(p1.score, p2.score));``` p1.score and p2.score is not defined - do you mean the score in the player class?

Comment: Assuming the class has getters, `People.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getScore));`

Comment: If the instance fields are declared private then you will need getters to access the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is how I did it. I used a record instead of a class as it creates the getters implicitly.  No setters since a record is immutable.

record and data string

```
record Data (int id, int score) {
  @Override
  public String toString() {
      return"id=%d, score=%d".formatted(id, score);
  }
}
String data = "1 456 2 100 3 600 1 400";
```

- create the list to hold the data
- split on one or more white space characters
- then for each `(id, score) pair`, create an instance of `Data` (I converted both to ints)
- add the instance to the list
- and sort the list

```
List<Data> list = new ArrayList<>();
String[] items = data.split("\\s+");
for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i+=2) {
    list.add(new Data(Integer.parseInt(items[i]), Integer.parseInt(items[i+1])));
}
list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Data::value));
for (Data d : list) {
    System.out.println(d);
}
```

prints

```
id=2, score=100
id=1, score=400
id=1, score=456
id=3, score=600
```

Answer (score 0):

Great question.

What you can do is use the score as the `key`, and use a list of id's at the `value`.

Consider the following.

```java
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> parse(String string) {
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new TreeMap<>();
    String[] strings = string.split(" ");
    int id, score;
    for (int index = 0; index < strings.length; index += 2) {
        id = Integer.parseInt(strings[index]);
        score = Integer.parseInt(strings[index + 1]);
        if (map.containsKey(score)) map.get(score).add(id);
        else map.put(score, new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(id)));
    }
    return map;
}
```

If we parsed a value of `"1 456 2 100 3 600 1 400"`, we get the following.

```
{100=[2], 400=[1], 456=[1], 600=[3]}
```

And, as demonstration, if parsed a value of `"1 456 2 100 3 600 1 400 5 456 6 600"`, we would get this.

```
{100=[2], 400=[1], 456=[1, 5], 600=[3, 6]}
```

Then, for access, you can implement a method similar to the following.

```java
/** @return null if not found */
List<Integer> scores(int id, Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map) {
    List<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Integer>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue().contains(id))
            scores.add(entry.getKey());
    }
    if (scores.isEmpty()) scores = null;
    return scores;
}
```

Output for `scores(1, parse("1 456 2 100 3 600 1 400"))` is the following.

```
[400, 456]
```